# The file path for initializing autoload.php is written twice

Tags: php

I run into this error when accessing the login page for site i'm working on on a local server:

> Warning: require(C:/xxampp/htdocsC:\xxampp\htdocs\trade\install\app\sr/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xxampp\htdocs\trade\app\views\login\login.php
>   on line
>   6
>
> Fatal error
>   : require(): Failed opening required 'C:/xxampp/htdocsC:\xxampp\htdocs\trade\install\app\sr/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xxampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xxampp\htdocs\trade\app\views\login\login.php
>   on line
>   6

The php code responsible for it

```
session_start();

require "../../../config/config.settings.php";

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].FILE_PATH."/vendor/autoload.php";

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].FILE_PATH."/app/src/MySQL/MySQL.php";
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].FILE_PATH."/app/src/App/App.php";
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].FILE_PATH."/app/src/App/AppModule.php";
```

Comment: What is `FILE_PATH`'s value? Do you need it in there? Or if `FILE_PATH` has the full path you need, do you actually need `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: Just checked. I dont need $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Removing it corrected the file paths. The error still stays. Any idea why?

Comment: `FILE_PATH` is not correct, missing one char: **c** at the end

Comment: yup. Finally fixed it. Initial paths i set for the project was wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.